# How does a jsp connect to a servlet object

Tags: jsp, servlets, connection

I'm learning JavaEE and meet a problem. It seems that there is a Servlet object in the back for each jsp page. but I don't understand where this servlet comes from.

For example suppose there is a jsp page called MyJsp.jsp, when I request this page, it seems that there is a MyJsp_jsp.java. So I wonder where it comes from.

Looking for some detail info about how the jsp page connecting to a servlet object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSP page is basically a web page with traditional HTML and bits of Java code. The file extension of a JSP page is .jsp rather than .html or .htm, which tells the server that this page requires special handling that will be accomplished by a server extension or a plug-in.

When a JSP page is called, it will be compiled (by the JSP engine) into a Java servlet. At this point the servlet is handled by the servlet engine, just like any other servlet. The servlet engine then loads the servlet class (using a class loader) and executes it to create dynamic HTML to be sent to the browser. The servlet creates any necessary object, and writes any object as a string to an output stream to the browser.